# Add content to csv with Add-Member

Tags: powershell

I've got a csv export from Active Directory which looks like this:

```
Name,"GivenName","Surname","Department","LogonWorkstations"
jdoe,"John","Doe","Finance","pc1"
fbueller,"Ferris","Bueller","Sales","pc2"
```

Now I want to search on each Workstation, check if a folder exists and write that information back into the csv.

```
$input = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\input.csv"

ForEach ($line in $input) {
    $wst = $line.LogonWorkstations
    If ($wst -ne "") {
        If (Test-Connection $wst -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            If (Test-Path "\\$wst\c$\Program Files\xyz" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                Add-Member -InputObject $line -NotePropertyName "xyz" -NotePropertyValue "exists"
            }
        }
    }
}

$input | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

As you can see in the code, Add-Member adds the additional information to `$input`, however the information isn't available after exporting it to csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. The problem is with If conditions.

```
$input = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\input.csv"

ForEach ($line in $input) {
    Add-Member -InputObject $line -NotePropertyName "xyz" -NotePropertyValue "exists"
}

$input # here I get the information

$input | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

I recommend to move `Add-Member` invocation as first command in the loop with default value (probably empty) then set the value in the condition.

```
ForEach ($line in $input) 
{
    Add-Member -InputObject $line -NotePropertyName "xyz" -NotePropertyValue $null
    $wst = $line.LogonWorkstations

    If ($wst -ne "") 
    {

        If (Test-Connection $wst -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
        {
            If (Test-Path "\\$wst\c$\Program Files\xyz" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
            {
                $line.xyz = 'exists'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you add the new member to the variable `$line` and expect it is written back to `$input` .. which is not.

try this:

```
$input = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\input.csv"

$counter=0

ForEach ($line in $input) {
    $wst = $line.LogonWorkstations
    If ($wst -ne "") {
        If (-not ( Test-Connection $wst -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            If (-not (Test-Path "\\$wst\c$\Program Files\xyz" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
                Add-Member -InputObject $input[$counter] -NotePropertyName "xyz" -NotePropertyValue "exists"
            }
        }
    }
    $counter++
}

$input # here I get the information

$input | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

I changed the `InputObject`-Parameter to write the new member to the `input` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for this kind of modification:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\input.csv" |
    Select-Object *, @{n='xyz';e={
        $wst = $_.LogonWorkstations
        if ($wst) {
            if (Test-Connection $wst -Count 1 -Quiet -EA SilentlyContinue) {
                $path = "\\$wst\c$\Program Files\xyz"
                [bool](Test-Path $path -EA SilentlyContinue)
            }
        }
    }} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\Scripts\output.csv' -NoType -Encoding Unicode
```